# A fast RSS Feed for twitter?

Tags: twitter, rss, feed

I'm trying to get the rss feed from a twitter to implement in a rss reader for desktop and website.

Tried queryfeed.net and twitrss.me but the updates are veery slow. On queryfeed takes about 3 hours and twitrss it's 30min-1hour.

The problem is a twitter from deals, and some deals have only 20 or 30min duration.

Thank you!